# How to hook into JavaScript event handler functions?

Tags: javascript, function, hook

We get many libraries out there which have their own UI components. Along with such components, they also have their own set of JavaScript code that handles events performed on these components. For example, if I were to use a single page theme in a CMS like Wordpress, it would have some JavaScript that handled the click on main navigation links to perform that scroll animation.
As I work on Accessibility, I would like to have for instance, the keyboard focus also to jump to target element that has been just animated into view port. I would like to have something like elem.clickHandlers.append(function(e) {...}); so that I can have my function pushed at end to run once all event handlers on the elem have been executed. Or if I wanted my function to be called before, I would like to have something like elem.clickHandlers.prepend(...).
Is there any JavaScript API that allows me to do the above?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: So in fact you need a way to read and manipulate the order of all event listeners, but all that without the need of triggering the event?

Comment: Check this out: [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2)

Comment: Thanks for that input. But Using that bookmarklet, I'm not getting the desired output. Rather it says only one event is attached to one display:none element.

Comment: Also I don't get any diagramatic out put for that single page. I am going through a Sharepoint page. I guess there should be events attached to fields like search for sure.